# Tkinter как индексируется Radiobutton в цикле

Tags: python, tkinter

код

```py
Otvet = [("Круглая", 1),("Квадртная",2),("Это Марс",3),("Вообще-то Луна",4)]

GlobalVar_Int = IntVar()
relY = float(0.1)

for Str_Otvet,Value_Otvet in Otvet:
    _Radiobutton = Radiobutton(windows, variable=GlobalVar_Int, fg="black", text=Str_Otvet, value=Value_Otvet, command=select)
    relY += 0.1
    _Radiobutton.place(relx=0.1,rely=relY)
```

Вопрос:
Как будет в цикле индексироваться _Radiobutton? как мне обратиться допустим конкретно к самому первому _Radiobutton который был создан в цикле? я хочу удалить все 4 radiobutton-а но и-за того что не знаю каким образом они индексируется удаляется только 4-тый элемент если писать _Radiobutton.destroy()

Answer (score 0):

```
Otvet = [("Круглая", 1),("Квадртная",2),("Это Марс",3),("Вообще-то Луна",4)]

GlobalVar_Int = IntVar()
relY = float(0.1)

R={} #словарь для хранения кнопкев 
for Str_Otvet,Value_Otvet in Otvet: #читай как правильно назыввать переменные
   R[Str_Otvet]=Radiobutton(windows, variable=GlobalVar_Int, fg="black", text=Str_Otvet, value=Value_Otvet, command=select)
    relY += 0.1 #хз чо тута
    R[Str_Otvet].place(relx=0.1,rely=relY)

R[("Круглая", 1)].destroy()
```

суть в словаре, имена могуть быть любые в том числе и по первому элементу кортежа

Answer (score 0):

Смог решить проблему списком и последующим удалением в цикле:

```py
Otvet = [("Круглая", 1),("Квадртная",2),("Это Марс",3),("Вообще-то Луна",4)]

GlobalVar_Int = IntVar()
relY = float(0.1)

list_Radiobutton = []

for Str_Otvet,Value_Otvet in Otvet:
    _Radiobutton = Radiobutton(windows, variable=GlobalVar_Int, fg="black", text=Str_Otvet, value=Value_Otvet, command=select)
    relY += 0.1
    _Radiobutton.place(relx=0.1,rely=relY)
    list_Radiobutton.append(_Radiobutton)

for radiobut in list_Radiobutton:
        radiobut.destroy()
```